# Method and property aliases with custom docstring in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, alias, docstring

I have implemented the following decorators:

```
class alias(object):

    """
    A decorator for implementing method aliases.
    """

    def __init__(self, *aliases):

        self.aliases = set(aliases)

    def __call__(self, obj):

        if type(obj) == property:
            obj.fget._aliases = self.aliases
        else:
            obj._aliases = self.aliases

        return obj

def aliased(aliased_class):

    """
    A decorator for enabling method aliases.
    """

    aliased_class_dict = aliased_class.__dict__.copy()
    aliased_class_set = set(aliased_class_dict)

    for name, method in aliased_class_dict.items():

        aliases = None

        if (type(method) == property) and hasattr(method.fget, '_aliases'):
            aliases = method.fget._aliases
        elif hasattr(method, '_aliases'):
            aliases = method._aliases

        if aliases:

            for a in aliases - aliased_class_set:
                setattr(aliased_class, a, method)

    return aliased_class
```

Below, an example of how I'm using them in order to create callable aliases of properties and methods:

```
@aliased
class MyClass(object):

    @alias('a')
    @property
    def alpha(self) -> float:

        """
        Returns the value of alpha.
        """

        return 2.5

    @alias('agt')
    def alpha_greater_than(value) -> bool:

        """
        Checks whether alpha is greater than the given value.
        """

        return self.alpha > value

mc = MyClass()
result = mc.agt(3.0)
# ...
```

Now I'm packaging out my project and building the documentation. At present, aliased methods and properties "inherit" the same docstring of the original entity. I would like to know if it's possible to manipulate the docstrings of aliased entities, at decorator level, so that they look like:

> This method/property is an alias of X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do can directly manipulate `X.__doc__` such as:

```
if aliases:

    for a in aliases - aliased_class_set:
        method.__doc__ = "This function is an alias of %s." % a
        setattr(aliased_class, a, method)
```

But the problem is that the original reference `X` will also be influenced. So you should better use a wrapper:

```
def aliased(aliased_class):

    """
    A decorator for enabling method aliases.
    """
    def wrapper(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return inner

    aliased_class_dict = aliased_class.__dict__.copy()
    aliased_class_set = set(aliased_class_dict)

    for name, method in aliased_class_dict.items():

        aliases = None

        if (type(method) == property) and hasattr(method.fget, '_aliases'):
            aliases = method.fget._aliases
        elif hasattr(method, '_aliases'):
            aliases = method._aliases

        if aliases:

            for a in aliases - aliased_class_set:
                wrapped_method = wrapper(method)
                wrapped_method.__doc__ = "This function is an alias of %s." % a
                setattr(aliased_class, a, wrapped_method)

    return aliased_class
```

And test:

```
print(mc.alpha_greater_than.__doc__)
print(mc.agt.__doc__)
```

Output:

```
        Checks whether alpha is greater than the given value.

This function is an alias of agt.
```

Comment: This works like a charm except for the fact that aliased entities lose their signature ant  type hints in the Sphinx documentation. "agt(value) -> bool", for example, becomes "agt(**kwargs)". Is there any way to preserve it?

Comment: Well, I didn't test it but I believe there is. I will modify my answer to use `functools.wraps`

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo I've checked that `functools.wraps` works perfectly :) See my update.