# Python: How to deprecate a function alias

Tags: python, function, alias, deprecated

As the title states, what I want to achieve is the following:
I have a python code base for which I want to rename all the functions from camelCasing to underscore_naming. In order to maintain backwards compatibility, I have renamed all the functions, but have created function aliases for all the old names. So far, so good.

Now what I want to do is add deprecation warnings to the function aliases, preferably in a fashion like this:

```
def do_something():
    ...


@deprecated(deprecated_in='2.0',
            details='All functions have been adapted to fit the PEP8 standard. Please use "do_something" instead')
doSomething = do_something
```

So that if somebody uses the old API call, they will get a deprecation warning. I've taken a look at  [deprecation](https://pypi.org/project/deprecation/) and [Deprecated](https://pypi.org/project/Deprecated/), but neither of them seem to work on aliases.

I realise that I can create a function definition for every deprecated name and decorate that, but that loses the elegance of the function alias, and makes for more mucky code. Does anybody have a good suggestion to achieve what I want?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a module `__getattr__`.

Answer (score 4):

I actually ended up going for a different solution, similar to what's suggested in [Method and property aliases with custom docstring in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54154256/method-and-property-aliases-with-custom-docstring-in-python).

I modified my code to

```
@alias('doSomething', deprecated=True)
def do_something():
    ...
```

and added a deprecation warning to the alias decorator.

Comment: Currently considering the added value of the deprecation tag. It doesn't really add all that much now, and the API looks fairly clean.